# MS Access Long Text field shows hashtag ####

Tags: ms-access-2016, hashtag, longtext

I have searched the solution for my MS Acccess hashtag (#'s) issue showing up in my Long Text field, but I cannot find it.

I have a Current Comment (txtCurComment) field (Long Text) on a form that allow users to enter a comment. A current date will be inserted in the front of that comment automatically. Next to this field, I have a button, Archive Comment, when clicked the Current Comment will be added into the Archived Comment (txtComments) (Long Text) field below it. The Current Comment field then will be cleared out to be ready for new current comment. Users can then enter next comment and so on. For some reasons, some of my users get the hashtags into these fields instead of their comments.

No format in the Properties of the Current Comment and Archived Comments fields.
It works as expected to most users. Only two users have this hashtags problem so far.
I use MS Access 2016.

Codes for the Current Comment field (Got Focus and Lost Focus events)

```
Private Sub txtCurComment_GotFocus()
   If Not Left(Me.txtCurComment, 8) = Format(Date, "MM/DD/YY") Then
        Me.txtCurComment = Format(Date, "MM/DD/YY") & ": " & Me.txtCurComment
   End If
End Sub
Private Sub txtCurComment_LostFocus()
    If Me.txtCurComment = Format(Date, "MM/DD/YY") & ": " then
        Me.txtCurComment = Null
     End If.
End Sub
```

Codes underlying the Archive Comment button.

```
Private Sub btnArchiveComment_Click()
     Me.txtComments = Me.txtCurComment & " " & Me.txtComments
     Me.txtCurComment = Null
End Sub
```

Everything seems working. I have no idea why the hashtags are showing up in those comments' fields to some users.  Can experts please help?
Thank you so much in advance.